# Make a table of remarks/figures, and format it as a table

Tags: ms-word

In my document, there is a "remarks" style that defines a numbered item "Remark # x" plus the paragraph text. Instances of this remarks style are spread throughout the document

```
<some text>
Remark #1: foo
<more text>
Remark #2: bar
<more text>
```

I am using a modified table of contents to show all remarks grouped at the beginning, with hyperlinks to the remark itself. Precisely, I insert a second TOC, and in the "options" dialog I uncheck all headings X styles and add only my custom "remarks" style.
This table is then formatted without using a style, because its formatting should be radically different from the standard table of contents (ultimately, its format is 'TOC 1 + bold + tabs x y + ...').

Currently, this list of remarks looks like

```
Remark #1: foo   ....................... 14
remark #2: bar   ....................... 19
```

I would like to make a table (as in a table with cells) to match those remarks to some more text, like

```
+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
| Remark             | link    | notes                         |
+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
| Remark #1: foo     | page 14 | some manually inserted text   |
+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
| Remark #2: bar     | page 19 | not relevant                  |
+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
```

And of course, if I can bind that to a style so that I don't loose formatting all the time, that would be great.